# Kafka connect transformations ExtractField$Value while preserving more keys

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have the following message structure:

```
{
    "payload" {
       "a": 1,
       "b": {"X": 1, "Y":2}          
    },
    "timestamp": 1659692671
}
```

I want to use SMTs to get the following structure:

```
{
   "a": 1,
   "b": {"X": 1, "Y":2},
   "timestamp": 1659692671
}
```

When I use ExtractField$Value for `payload`, I cannot preserve `timestamp`.
I cannot use `Flatten` because `"b"`'s structure should not be flatten.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, moving a field into another Struct isn't possible with the built-in transforms. You'd have to write your own, or use a stream-processing library before the data reaches the connector.

Note that Kafka records themselves have a timestamp, so do you really need the timestamp as a field in the value? One option is to [extract the timestamp](https://jcustenborder.github.io/kafka-connect-documentation/projects/kafka-connect-transform-common/transformations/ExtractTimestamp.html), then flatten, then [add it back](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/transforms/insertfield.html). However, this will *override* the timestamp that the producer had set with that value.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for taking the time to give me an answer. Unfortunately, in my case I want to preserve the timestamp, which is not even the producer's timestamp but even the producer is proxing from another source. I will give it a try to add a custom transformation.